# How do I get data under a specific user into template in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, database, django-models, django-templates

I have a very simple Django project. I have setup the login and sign up already to work but my one problem is that in models.py file looks like this :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class ProductRecord(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    print_process = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    finish = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    product_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='productImages', blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name


class UserOrder(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    url = models.URLField()
    reorder = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    users = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    social_site = models.URLField(blank=True)
    orders = models.ForeignKey(UserOrder, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=3)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.users.username
```

Now in admin I can make an order and then in the UserProfiles assign that order to an account but how can I make the user when he or she logs in see his orders after I assign them via my admin panel?

Answer (score 0):

Check if `user.is_authenticated`. Assuming user profiles are created automatically upon signup, try something like:

EDIT (try this, it will work):
Try this, change your UserOrders model to resemble this...

```py
class UserOrder(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    url = models.URLField()
    reorder = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

and your profile model to resemble this:

```py
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    social_site = models.URLField(blank=True)    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.users.username
```

then, in your view:

```py
def your_view(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        orders = UserOrders.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    else:
        pass # or do something else
    return render(request, 'your_template.html', locals())
```

Check if there are orders at your_template.html:

```html
{% if orders%}
{%for order in orders%}
{{order.id}} <!-- or interpolate something else like product_name -->
{%endfor %}
{%endif%}
```

Comment: ```orders = profile.orders``` in my code sample calls the orders, you just need to call the new ```orders``` variable in you template... An easier way for all this would be to have a field called user in the UserOrder table which is a ForeignKey to the Users table. I think it's more intuitive and easier to work with

Comment: I think it would be easier for both of us if you edit your question to include the entire UserProfile, UserOrders models, the view function and the relevant template section... That way, it will be more clear what we are discussing

Comment: I am now getting error Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: id, orders, orders_id, social_site, users, users_id

Comment: try changing ```profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)``` to ```profile = UserProfile.objects.get(users=request.user)```

Comment: amend the models like in the updated answer. it should work

Comment: I can't! it gives error that user is not recognised or available

Comment: ) from e
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'user'. i get this error

Comment: what do i put in default for those foreignkeys statements?

Comment: what do I put as default?? it is saying to add default and then I get another stupid error! so frustrating!!